# RegEx - How to get rid of everything between these two brackets, including the brackets?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am making NO headway in writing a regular expression and need some help.

I need to get rid of everything between two brackets including the two brackets.

I have tried everything I could think of with no luck.

```
<cfscript>
MyString = "Eat some [pizza] with beer.";
MyString = reReplaceNoCase(MyString, "", "", "all");
writeOutput(MyString);
</cfscript>
```

In a text editor, I was using the following string and it worked perfectly well, but I can't get it working in ColdFusion.

```
^[*^]
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\[[^\]]*]
```

You have to escape the brackets or they will be interpreted as "any character inside these brackets"