# PHP remove delimited placeholders from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to remove some chunks from a string, which is basically html code; the chunks are delimited by **#**
I'm a zero with regexp, but found this method on another SO topic ([Replace everything between and including two characters using regex in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051505/replace-everything-between-and-including-two-characters-using-regex-in-php)) but it's not working and I'm not able to get why.
My chunks are placeholders inside html code, like this :

**#TEXT_2#**

and I'tried with these functions (none of them succeeded):

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[[#]]*]/', '', $text);
$text = preg_replace("/\\#\\\(\d).*?\\#/", "", $text);
$text = preg_replace( '~\#(\d+)\#~' , "", $text);
```

Can anybody suggest me a way to do it ?
Any help would be higly appreciated.
Thx

Comment: What's the expected output ?

Comment: the output should be the whole string (i.e. html code) without the placeholders, including the delimiters '#'

Comment: Edit your question with actual input and expected output. A slight change in a regex might cause it to not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/#\w+#/', '', $text);
```

Comment: `\w` == `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so you can remove that underscore

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "#in1#out1#in2#out2#in3###out3";
$text = preg_replace('/#[^#]*#/', '', $text);
echo $text, PHP_EOL;
```

it should echo only the out parts i.e.: `out1out2out3`